# The datagridview vertical scrollbar loses its value after I delete a row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have a datagridview with a datatable as the datasource inside a tabcontrol.   I load the datatable with 10 rows of data then set the datasource.  Whenever I delete a row from the datagridview or the data source datatable, the vertical scrollbar on the datagridview loses its settings.  I have tried from the datatable:

```
DataTable dataTableCopy = ((DataSet)dgvFeedItems.DataSource).Tables[0];
for (int i = 0; i < dataTableCopy.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if (dataTableCopy.Rows[i][0].ToString() == FeedItemID.ToString())
    {
        dataTableCopy.Rows[i].Delete();
        break;
    }
}
dataTableCopy.AcceptChanges();
```

I have tried directly from the grid:

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvrFeedItem in dgvFeedItems.Rows)
 {
     if (dgvrFeedItem.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals(FeedItemID.ToString()))
     {
          dgvFeedItems.Rows.Remove(dgvrFeedItem);
          break;
     }
 }
```

The result from either method is the same.

Before:

[image: Before row deletion]

After:

[image: After row deletion]

In both cases, the table has the correct number of rows, but the vertical scrollbar is gone.  TY for any suggestions and help.

Comment: After removing the entry, you also see the grid has scrolled up - the first entry now is "caribbean360". It appears the grid really thinks there is no more data to display. Is "caribbean360" the first link, or is "wusfnews" the last link?

Comment: I deleted the ninth row. "wusfnews" was the 10th row and is the new 9th row in the after image.  But I still cannot scroll back up to the top.  I have deleted the first, 2nd, and middle rows, the behavior is the same, the scroll bar fails after the delete.

Comment: In addition, the datatable and the gridview rowcounts are both correct at 10 before and 9 after the deletion.

Comment: I followed up on the "grid thinks there is no more data".  When the data is missing the vertical scroll bar disappears completely.  So it still thinks there is enough data for a scroll, but the bar is not displaying correctly.  Lastly I can use the cursor keys to scroll up and down through the list.

Answer (score 1):

Try `view.BindingContext = new BindingContext();`

It worked for me to reset the vertical scroll bar range.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find out why it isn't functioning correctly, but I did find a work around in case anyone else has this problem.  Basically after deleting the row from the DataTable, the vertical scrollbar inside the datagridview is being disabled.  So as a work around, I find the vertical scrollbar control in the datagridview, store its' position, update the datatable, re-enabled the vertical scroll bar, then reposition the vertical scroll bar because it's setting was lost when it was disabled.

```
VScrollBar vsbFeedGrid = null;
// The vscrollbar index is 1 in this.dgvFeedItems.Controls but I loop in case it isnt always in that position
foreach (Control control in this.dgvFeedItems.Controls)
{
    if (control is VScrollBar)
    {
        vsbFeedGrid = (VScrollBar)control;
        break;
    }
}

if (vsbFeedGrid != null)
{
    int intCurrentVPosition = vsbFeedGrid.Value;  // Store current scroll position

    DeleteItemFromFeedGrid(lngFeedItemID);  // Update datatable

    vsbFeedGrid.Enabled = true;             //Re-enable the vertical scrollbar

    if (intCurrentVPosition > vsbFeedGrid.Maximum)  //Re-position the vertical scrollbar
    {
        vsbFeedGrid.Value = vsbFeedGrid.Maximum;  // In case it was the last record deleted
    }
    else
    {
        vsbFeedGrid.Value = intCurrentVPosition;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little code improvement of a previous answer:

```
foreach(var sb in grid.Controls.OfType<ScrollBar>())
{
    int intCurrentPosition = sb.Value;
    sb.Enabled = true;
    if (intCurrentPosition > sb.Maximum)
        sb.Value = sb.Maximum;
    else
        sb.Value = intCurrentPosition;
}
```

Works for both scrollbars